# XSL-FO on Windows without Java

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm working on a .NET web project and need to generate PDFs from XSL-FO. I've tried [FO.NET](http://fonet.codeplex.com/) but it spits out various "not implemented yet" warnings when I try to apply it to our input and generates a (visually) broken PDF. We're in a situation where running Java on all of our servers would be too costly, so we can't use any of the Java libraries around in lieu of FO.NET. I found [xmlroff](http://www.xmlroff.org/) but I'm not sure it even builds/runs properly on cygwin.

One possibility would be to have a dedicated server which hosts a Java web service which runs one of the XSL-FO libs, this of course would mean server and admin costs.

Does anyone know any XSL-FO libraries that run natively on windows and without Java? Alternatively are there any other feasible workarounds than the web service one I mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Think my response is quite late but nevertheless.

You have Ibex pdf creator from Ibex. They have support for both .NET and Java.

[IBEX](http://www.xmlpdf.com/downloads-net.html)

We use in our project and it works a charm.

Hope this helps

VATSAG

Comment: Thanks for the response, we settled for installing Java on a server but it's good to have an alternative for future reference.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, have you used any tool to generate the XSL-FO or have you manually wrote the entire stylesheet by yourself.

Comment: We have XSL-stylesheets from a 3rd party which we use to transform our own XML into FO.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a pure port of `Apache FOP version 2.8` that runs in `.Net Core`. Check it out:

https://github.com/sorcerdon/FOP.NetCore

Here is the nuget:

[image: NuGet version (FOP.NetCore)]

Since this is a pure port, that means that it can do anything that Apache FOP can do and does not require Java be installed on the machine.